# Help convert SQL statement to LINQ Lambda (need help with group by and sum)

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008, .net-4.0

Here's the statement to convert to LINQ to SQL (Lambda please)

SELECT [Date], SUM(counted) [Counted], 
SUM(Time) [Time]
FROM dbo.TableName
GROUP BY [Date]

This is the raw data without group by and sum

```
Date                    Counted Time
2011-09-07 00:00:00.000 34      31
2011-09-07 00:00:00.000 6       3
2011-09-07 00:00:00.000 7       3
2011-09-07 00:00:00.000 6       2
2011-09-07 00:00:00.000 7       2
2011-09-07 00:00:00.000 19      4
2011-09-07 00:00:00.000 13      4
2011-09-07 00:00:00.000 11      4
2011-09-07 00:00:00.000 14      3
2011-09-07 00:00:00.000 0.75    3
```

These are the results after group by and sum are applied

```
Date                    Counted Time
2011-09-07 00:00:00.000 117.75  59
```

This is what I have so far, but I'm very confused when it comes to doing the group by and sum.  Obviously my syntax is way off lol.

```
var q = context.TableName.Where(...)
               .GroupBy(x => new { x.Date})
               .Sum(x => x.Counted, x.Time????)
               .Select(x => x.Date, x.Counted, x.Time;
```

Comment: Do you have data in DataTable? As far as I can see you have, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var q = context.TableName
           .GroupBy(x => x.Date)
           .Select(g => new { 
               Date = g.Key,
               Counted = g.Sum(x => x.Counted), 
               Time = g.Sum(x => x.Time)
           });
```

Answer (score 0):

What about usng Sum() extension method:

```
var query = table.AsEnumerable().Select(s => s.Field<int>("counted")).Sum();
```